# How to make an object in blender game engine react with different collision differently

Tags: game-engine

I used collision sensor which reacts to any kind of collision which takes place. So is there any other way to make an object react with different collision differently.

[image]

The cube is a ridged body and the plane is static

[image]

As the cube falls the plane detects the cube collision and acts as set.

[image]

These are the given settings for the above function.

As the cube falls the plane senses the cube collision and does the given function. But if there would be an extra object, for example a sphere, I want the plane object to react with the sphere collision differently. How is it possible in blender game engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the collision evaluation

- by Property (M/P disabled Property: contains a property name)
- by Material (M/P enabled Material: contains a material name)
- no Filter at all (all other cases).

[image]

Be aware - the other participant of the collision needs to have the property/material.

Comment: I was going to do this in a long method. Thanks